# Zip file and print to stdout

Tags: linux, zip

I need archive file with zip and print zip-data to stdout in realtime.
Standard zip program may create zip file only.
This can do gzip with -c attribute, but it use gzip algorithm.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `zip` program from Info-ZIP (the one usually found on Linux systems) allows generating ZIP files into the standard output, when you use `-` as the name of the file. For example you could send a zip file to port 8787 on a remote host with this command:

```
zip -r - files_to_be_archived | nc remotehost 8787
```

All of this is documented on the [zip command manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip).

Comment: Excellent!
This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: For copying small files to another server, when I don't want to establish a network connection to copy them, I'll `zip -r - *|base64 -w0` and then pipe that to `base64 --decode` on the other side, and unzip it.