# How to output base64 from a directory zipping

Tags: linux, bash, zip, backup, tar

I'm on a server that **hasn't enough disk space**.
I'd like to backup all the files by zipping a directory and directly output it in base64 only in bash.

I tried to zip this directory, but my server doesn't have enough disk space.

Is there a way to create a zip (or a tar) archive and output the base64 in live ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I've found my answer with this command:

```
zip -r - directory_to_archive/ | base64
```

Source: [Zip file and print to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933975/zip-file-and-print-to-stdout)